# Issue with tkinter Root Window and Radio Button GUI Generation

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

As someone new to tkinter for Python 3, I am having a couple of little issues navigating how to generate a GUI (in context of a Python script) despite reading the documentation and Stack Overflow answers. My objective is to create a frame with 7 radio button choices each corresponding to a screen resolution size which when selected and the submit button is pressed, the selected radio button will pass its value to a variable. However when I implement my GUI, I get two issues.

The first is that my frame opens correctly with the radio buttons, but another frame, which is blank and is titled "tk" appears. Regardless of what I do (i.e. use `root.withdraw()` etc. as others have mentioned), this blank window still appears.

The second and more baffling issue I am having is that when generated, all but the first radio button is selected, not normally with a dot in the center, but with a hyphen. Now the user can press on the option he/she wants and it will all unselect except for the choice, but it doesn't look normal and would probably confuse the user. I read about setting tristatevariable to none yet that didn't work (or at least in my trial). I also tried to force a `deselect()` function on all of the radio buttons before they generate and that didn't work either. Also, keep in mind that the radio buttons' variable must handle a string and not an int. What is happening here and how can I fix it?

The code snippet that pertains to both of these seemingly related issues is as follows:

```
if urldata == None:
                class ResolutionInputGUI:
                    def __init__(self, master):
                        self.master = master
                        master.title("My GUI")

                        self.label = tk.Label(master, text="Your Screen Resolution Is: " + screenres + "\n")
                        self.label.pack()

                        MODES = [
                            ("500×500", "500×500"),
                            ("1280×800", "1280×800"),
                            ("1280×1024", "1280×1024"),
                            ("1440×900", "1440×900"),
                            ("1680×1050", "1680×1050"),
                            ("1920×1080", "1920×1080"),
                            ("1920×1200", "1920×1200")
                        ]

                        resolution = tk.StringVar()
                        resolution.set("500×500")

                        for text, mode in MODES:
                            self.radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(master, text=text, variable=resolution, value=mode)
                            self.radiobutton.pack(anchor=tk.W)

                        self.submit_button = tk.Button(master, text="Submit", command=self.submit)
                        self.submit_button.pack()

                        self.cancel_button = tk.Button(master, text="Cancel", command=self.cancelbutton)
                        self.cancel_button.pack()

                    def submit(self):
                        global screenres
                        screenres = self.radiobutton.get()
                        root.quit()
                        self.master.destroy()
                        print(screenres)

                    def cancelbutton(self):
                        raise SystemExit

                root = tk.Tk()
                my_gui = ResolutionInputGUI(root)
                root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cant seem to solve this issue and tkinter seems to be much more complicated than originally thought. Also, is there anything else that I am doing inefficiently here or to make the end user experience more "friendly?" Thank you so much!

Comment: There's something wrong with your indentation

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, for some reason I couldn't get it to indent properly after the "if" statement for inputting it for Stack Overflow. It runs, it's just having the issues explained above.

Comment: we can only go by what we see. Please take the time to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first is that my frame opens correctly with the radio buttons, but another frame, which is blank and is titled "tk" appears

This is because you are calling `Tk()` twice. I see one of them near the end, and you must have another elsewhere in your code.

> all but the first radio button is selected, not normally with a dot in the center, but with a hyphen.

This is because you are using a local variable. Change "resolution" to "self.resolution".

> when selected and the submit button is pressed, the selected radio button will pass its value to a variable

To do this you need to return the value from the *variable*, not from the button.

Also, you should put the class definition at the global level.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ResolutionInputGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("My GUI")

        self.label = tk.Label(master, text="Your Screen Resolution Is: " + screenres + "\n")
        self.label.pack()

        MODES = [
            ("500×500", "500×500"),
            ("1280×800", "1280×800"),
            ("1280×1024", "1280×1024"),
            ("1440×900", "1440×900"),
            ("1680×1050", "1680×1050"),
            ("1920×1080", "1920×1080"),
            ("1920×1200", "1920×1200")
        ]

        self.resolution = tk.StringVar(master, value="500×500")

        for text, mode in MODES:
            self.radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(master, text=text, variable=self.resolution, value=mode)
            self.radiobutton.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        self.submit_button = tk.Button(master, text="Submit", command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.pack()

        self.cancel_button = tk.Button(master, text="Cancel", command=self.cancelbutton)
        self.cancel_button.pack()

    def submit(self):
        global screenres
        screenres = self.resolution.get()
        root.quit()
        self.master.destroy()
        print(screenres)

    def cancelbutton(self):
        raise SystemExit

if urldata == None:
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_gui = ResolutionInputGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This did the trick; thank you so much! I did have another tk window generated and I guess because it was never closed, it reappears. I was able to get rid of the window using root.withdraw() but anything else (like .destroy) didn't do anything. Is this the correct way to handle closing that tk window which was busted used to measure screen resolution? Also, thank you for the tip on keeping the class global. From an OOP, point of view, what is the benefit of this if the class will only be called once with the if statement? Just wanted to know for future reference. Thanks again!

Comment: The correct way is to not destroy it. Reuse it. So don't make a new "root", use the old one. Keeping the class definition global is important if you want to reuse it (which you may want to do someday) and it also keeps the code neat. Also, it allows you to move the class definition to another file if you want.